exports is not defined in ES module scope AND require() of ES Module not supported
Okay so i seem to be stuck in a loop. I received the error: "exports is not defined in ES module scope". Looking at other people having this issue it seemed that it was resolved by adding "type": "module" to their package.json file. When doing this i instead receive the error: "require() of ES Module not supported". Looking at other people they seem to solve this by removing "type": "module" from their package.json file. Doing this obviously just takes me back to step one though. What am i to do here?
tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES5",
      "module": "ES6",
      "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
      "lib": ["es2015"],
      "sourceMap": true
    }
}


Seems like your code or the libraries you use has a mix of CommonJS and Module exports. So, Fixing one makes the other one to throw error.

"Looking at other people having this issue it seemed that it was resolved by adding
"type": "module" to their package.json file" - no. You also need to actually stop using exports in your code!

Why do you use target: ES5?

@Bergi Not sure to be honest, think i saw it in the TS docs somewhere. Doing some further testing it seems that my tsconfig.json is irrelevant in my case so i have removed it for now. To provide a simple example: import foo from 'bar' will be compiled into:  var foo = require("bar"). Changing this to use the import syntax instead of require will make the code functional. However i am not sure i understand the behavior, why is require the default behavior? And how can/should i use import statements instead? Also not sure what you mean by needing to stop using "exports" Can you elaborate?

Wait where exactly do you receive the error "require() of ES Module not supported" if it's only in the transpiled code?

And yes, you will need to have a .tsconfig and change some options there to make it compile differently
